# Kernel-mode driver for detecting webcam access

Tags: winapi, kernel, driver, webcam

I am working on writing a kernel-level driver that detects if any process accesses the webcam, and reports to a user-mode application. Currently, there are multiple ways of accessing and controlling the webcam like Directshow, along with various VisualBasic projects.

Please share with me a single way of detecting all accesses to the webcam. Are there any native APIs that can be monitored at the kernel level, which are common to all processes accessing the webcam?

Answer (score 0):

what kind of os you are using? you may check the devic's object structure and there should be a link list to process open that device or a count that counts number of process open it.